# how to write sql query from sas based on if then statements

Tags: sql, sas, oracle-sqldeveloper

I don't really have any advanced sql knowledge on how to phrase if/then statements in sql (whether to use case, for example) and/or formatting variables in the same query so I was wondering if someone could help with this sas code and phrasing it in the correct format into sql:

```
data convert_code;

format date1 date 2 mmddyy8. code $4.;

set userid.code; (this table is pulled from oracle)

if ID='X' then P='A'; else P='B';

If CAT in ('1','2','3') then CAT_group='ONE'; else CAT_GROUP='TWO';

if CAT_2 > '0' and CAT_2A >='1' then d=1; else d=0;

date1=datepart(date1);

date2=datepart(date2);

if code='3' and type_code in ('A','B','C') THEN DO;

if P_CODE in ('1','2','3') then P='1';

if P_CODE in ('4','5','6') then P='2';

end;

if code='4' and e_code in ('A') then DO;

if B_CODE in ('11','12','13') then P='3';

if B_CODE in ('14','15','16') then P='4';

end;

run;
```

Comment: Is it SAS SQL or another SQL? Yes, Case statements are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example given here uses SAS' `proc sql` language. If you are using a different SQL implementation then the syntax may be different. However, the `case` expression examples should be fairly easy to adapt to any SQL implementation as it is part of the SQL standard.

```
proc sql;
    /* Name your output table */
    create table convert_code as
    select
        /* 
            Unlike the data step variables from the input data are not
            selected by default, you can request them individually or
            with "select *" 
        */
        /* Use "format =" after the column definition to set its format */
        code format = $4.,
        /* Use SAS functions as normal, name the output variable with "as" */
        datepart(date1) as date1 format = mmddyy8.,
        /* Comma separate each variable you want in your output */
        datepart(date2) as date2 format = mmddyy8.,
        /* A "case" expression can conditionally set a variable to a value */
        case 
            when CAT in ('1', '2', '3') then 'ONE'
            else 'TWO'
        /* Close the "case" statement with "end" */
        end as CAT_group,
        /* You can nest case statements to emulate your "then do" */
        case 
            when code = '3' and e_code in ('A', 'B', 'C') then 
                case 
                    /* Use multiple "when then"s to emulate "else if" */
                    when P_CODE in ('1', '2', '3') then '1'
                    when P_CODE in ('4', '5', '6') then '2'
                    else ''
                end
            when code = '4' and e_code in ('A') then 
                case 
                    when P_CODE in ('11', '12', '13') then '3'
                    when P_CODE in ('14', '15', '16') then '4'
                    else ''
                end
            when ID = 'X' then 'A'
            else 'B'
        end as P,
        /* An alternative to case is to use the "ifn()" or "ifc()" functions */
        ifn(CAT_2 > 0 and CAT_2A >= 1, 1, 2) as d
    /* Choose the input data and end the query with a ";" */
    from userid.code;
    /* 
        Additional processing can be done here, some examples include:
            "where": limit the input
            "left join", "right join", "inner join", "outer join", ",":
                combine with additional data sets
            "group by": group based on column values for summary functions
            "order by": specify which columns to sort the output by
    */
/* End the "proc sql" processing */
quit;
```

Using `case` expressions rather than the the SAS specific `ifn()` and `ifc()` functions would be my suggestion, as they are the standard SQL method for conditionally assigning values and will (probably) be the same in other SQL implementations. Be aware that `format =` and the `datepart()` function are SAS specific.

- A brief exploration of `proc sql` from a `data` step perspective can be found [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/nesug99/ad121.pdf)
- The `case` expression [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473682.htm)
- The `ifn()` and `ifc()` functions [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002604573.htm)
- The `format =` column modifier [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473684.htm)